# matplotlib: how to simultaneously change tick position and figure shape

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a figure and hope to set the figure shape and tick positions. But I find that I cannot do the two things together. For example, if I use the following code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ls = range(0,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# set figure shape
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.ylim([0,10])
plt.plot(ls)
figname = 'aaa.jpg'
# set ytick positions
ax.set_yticks([1,3,5,7,9])
plt.savefig(figname,format='jpg')
```

Then I get the following figure.
[image]

The shape is correct. But the `ytick` is not changed by the code line `ax.set_yticks([1,3,5,7,9])`.

Then I try the following code (i.e. move the sentence `plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))` to the beginning of the program):

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set figure shape
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ls = range(0,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.ylim([0,10])
plt.plot(ls)
figname = 'aaa.jpg'
# set ytick position
ax.set_yticks([1,3,5,7,9])
plt.savefig(figname,format='jpg')
```

Then I get the following figure:

[image]

The `ytick` is correct. Yicks appear in positions `[1,3,5,7,9]`. However, the figure shape is not the shape I set.

How to do the two things together?

Thank you all for helping me!!!

Comment: both plots show the same figure, what's wrong in the second figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the `figsize` in the  `subplot` function instead.

what went wrong in the first graph:

```
 plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
```

the above line of code is creating a new figure on which your graph is being plotted, the 'ax' on which you are setting the y ticks is related to  a subplot which is different.

```
ls = range(0,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

ax.set_yticks([1,3,5,7,9])
ax.set_xticks([1,3,5,7,9])

plt.grid()
plt.plot(ls)
```

The plot is showing exactly what you're trying to do

[image: graph]